# How to call ws WebSocket and wait for response in Express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ws

I have setup Nodejs to serve an HttpServer using ExpressJs. I also need to use `ws` WebSocket in order to connect to my device for fetching data.

My attempt is now this.

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import http from 'http';
import { WebSocketServer } from 'ws';

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

//initialize a simple http server
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({ port: 7777});

wsServer.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        ws.send('{"msg":"getdata"}');
        ws.on('message', function message(data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            res.json(data);
        });
    });
    
    //start our server
    httpServer.listen(7778, () => {
        console.log(`Server started on port ${httpServer.address().port} :)`);
    });
});
```

The problem is that when the API is called more than once. An error `code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'` is thrown. I assume it is because the `ws.on('message')` is executed multiple times. So, I am trying to find a way to remove the listener but to no avail.

Is there any better way to do this? I just want to have a webserver that calls to another websocket in order to get data from a device.

Comment: You want to send `a message from websocket` as `/` API response?

Comment: @TamilVendhanKanagarasu Yes, this is for Proof of Concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your code example to work, message on websocket must be sent after the `/` request is made. Because, before that, on `message` handler is not registered. Also, once handling the first request successfully, you cannot send a websocket message again. Because, when you do that, the `res` in the `message` handler is already completed. So, you will get `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT`. Thus proved :-)

So, your API calls must be like in the following pattern

- / Call #1
- Websocket message #1
- / Call #2
- Websocket message #2

If you do so, you will not get the `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT` error. Because, `res` is send once for every `/` request.

Comment: This is the whole point of my assumption. I want solution.

Comment: RPC is your solution. Let me post a sample!

Comment: Also, this websocket server, is it the same server or something else?

Comment: They are on the same server.

Comment: If they are on the same server, why do you need to use websocket to get the data? Can you clarify about the use case?

Comment: The device only uses WebSocket as the communication protocol so I need to use WebSocket to get and send data between my server and the device. Another thing is that there must be a website, which uses Http/Https server so I also need this one, which will get the data from the WebSocket server (from the device actually).

Comment: @holydragon, in that case, you need to have some kind of data store on server. 
Websocket messages shall be stored in there. API requests will simply fetch from the store & display. Website also shall do the same. 

If you keep the websocket messages transient(ie: receiving messages on API request), how would it work from website? 

To provide further suggestion, you need to give more information.

Comment: There is a device. It has some information. You make a call to a server. On the call, the server will call the device over websocket to get the message or the device has to send a message on that very instant of the request? 
This is something that you need to think about. It is good to keep things decoupled. So, the device can send the message periodically. The server will store that information in database or file, etc. Whenever the API request comes, based on some query parameter, you return the data.

Answer (score 0):

this will solve your error code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'

```
 wsServer.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {
        app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    //first This
       ws.on('message', function message(data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                res.json(data);
            });
    //then use this
            ws.send('{"msg":"getdata"}');
         
        });
        
        //start our server
        httpServer.listen(7778, () => {
            console.log(`Server started on port ${httpServer.address().port} :)`);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Just call ws.on before ws.send? I tried it but still got the same error.

Comment: you are using res.json and ws.send only one res. method work. remove any one

Comment: what? there is only res.json

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var timeout = require('connect-timeout');
var uuid = require('uuidv4');
var _ = require('lodash');

app.use(timeout('10s'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

let responses = []

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('res', (e) => {
        var obj = _.find(responses, r => r.id === e.id);
        obj.res.send(e)
        _.remove(responses, r => r.id === e.id);
    })
})

app.get('/endpoint', (req, res) => {
    const id = uuid()
    io.emit('req', { id, ip: req.ip, header: req.headers, method: req.method });
    responses.push({ id, res })
});

http.listen(3000);
```

If you want over multiple instance, you can use redis pub sub.